# PHP libgd crash without feedback

Tags: php, debugging, crash, gd

I'm working on a very large number of images. I have to create four JPEG versions of each image:

- original size JPEG
- 700x430 version
- 57x57 thumbnail
- 167xN thumbnail (variable height, maintain aspect ratio)

I used the following two helper functions:

```
function thumbFixed($srcfile, $dstfile, $dstWidth, $dstHeight) {
    $srcImg = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($srcfile));
    list($srcWidth, $srcHeight) = getimagesize($srcfile);
    $srcAR = $srcWidth / $srcHeight;

    $dstAR = $dstWidth / $dstHeight;

    $dstImg = imagecreatetruecolor($dstWidth, $dstHeight);

    if($srcAR >= $dstAR) {
        $cropHeight = $dstHeight;
        $cropWidth = (int)($dstHeight * $srcAR);
    } else {
        $cropWidth = $dstWidth;
        $cropHeight = (int)($dstWidth / $srcAR);
    }

    $cropImg = imagecreatetruecolor($cropWidth, $cropHeight);
    imagecopyresampled($cropImg, $srcImg, 0, 0, 0, 0, $cropWidth, $cropHeight, $srcWidth, $srcHeight);

    $dstOffX = (int)(($cropWidth - $dstWidth) / 2);
    $dstOffY = (int)(($cropHeight - $dstHeight) / 2);

    imagecopy($dstImg, $cropImg, 0, 0, $dstOffX, $dstOffY, $dstWidth, $dstHeight);
    imagejpeg($dstImg, $dstfile);
}

function thumbGrid($srcfile, $dstfile, $dstWidth) {
    $srcImg = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($srcfile));
    list($srcWidth, $srcHeight) = getimagesize($srcfile);
    $srcAR = $srcWidth / $srcHeight;

    $dstHeight = $dstWidth / $srcAR;

    $dstImg = imagecreatetruecolor($dstWidth, $dstHeight);

    imagecopyresampled($dstImg, $srcImg, 0, 0, 0, 0, $dstWidth, $dstHeight, $srcWidth, $srcHeight);
    imagejpeg($dstImg, $dstfile);
}
```

Those function are used in this context:

```
$img = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($local));
imagejpeg($img, 'temp.jpg', 100);
thumbFixed($local, 'gallery.jpg', 700, 430);
thumbFixed($local, 'thumbsmall.jpg', 57, 57);
thumbGrid($local, 'grid.jpg', 167);
```

Where `$local` holds the pathname of the image.

The code works okay for most of the pictures, but misbehaves in one particular case, which is a 1792x1198, 356Kb JPEG file. I'm quite worried by the misbehavior, though, because I can't seem to trace it in any way: running `gdb` on PHP interpreter results in `Program exited with code 0377.` (which means PHP has `exit(-1)`ed) and nothing else - no stack trace, no errors, no feedback whatsoever.

I figured out, by inserting various echos before every libgd call, that the script "crashes" PHP when executing `$cropImg = imagecreatetruecolor($cropWidth, $cropHeight);` in the `thumbFixed` function, but I can't seem to figure out a way around this since I can't control it from my code, nor backtrace it from a debugger. Has anybody had similar experiences with this and can give me some pointers?

Comment: Some versions of gdlib are known to have a bug in alpha channel handling. What version are you using?

Comment: @arkascha gd_info says `bundled (2.0.34 compatible)`, PHP's version is 5.4.4 bundled with MAMP.

Comment: Version 2.0.34 should be fixed to that aspect. Sorry, that was just an idea.

Comment: @arkascha I tried running another version of PHP (5.3.15) with the same version of GD and it runs flawlessly. I suspect there is some bug somewhere, since even in case of misconfiguration this is not an acceptable behavior from the PHP interpreter.

Comment: I never claimed the software is bug free. I just said that this well known bug I mentioned has been corrected for version 2.0.34. That does not mean there aren't any other bugs or other things going wrong.

Comment: @arkascha I wasn't implying that :) I was just stating that there might indeed be a bug, or some badly written exception handling code, somewhere in the PHP interpreter so that future readers of this page stumbling into a similar problem could have some pointers about what happened, which complements your (correct) statement about libgd bug being fixed. :)